# Dividing whole column in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm a relatively new user to Google Spreadsheet.

I'd like every cell in the «B» column to be the result of what's in the «A» column (in the same row) but divided by 5.

B1, B2, B3, etc. (the quotients) should be A1, A2, A3, etc. (the dividents) divided by 5 (the divisor).

In example: `B1 = (A1)/5`.

I know the formula for doing it one by one is placing i.e. `=DIVIDE(A1,5)` in the B1 cell, and to place `=DIVIDE(A2,5)` in the B2 cell, etc. — but this would be as complicated as calculating every cell manually.

The goal is to automatically fill in the quotient of the (`A[*same row number*]/5`) in the (`B[*same row number*]`) column.

But how do I translate/replace what I call for [same row number] to the language or formula that Google Spreadsheets understands, because I guess there is a formula for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is called [cell reference](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/2/) in Excel or spreadsheet lingo.

Use the formula `=DIVIDE($A1,5)` and drag the cell handle down across all the cells. Here is my sample.

[image: formula in cell A1]

When I dragged the first cell to the end, this is what google spreadsheet did

[image: dragged version of formula]

Result with values

[image]

Comment: u the best Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(A1:A/5; 0)
```