# How do I make Google Spreadsheet automatically divide a column into another column?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet that includes a long list of values, with a column that contains a total of values, and after that an average of the values in the row. I need the averaged column to always be 1/6 of the value in the summed column, but I can't figure out a way to make it automatically calculate it for me for each new row.

So far, I have been doing it all manually (type out all the values, manually add them together for the total, then divide by 6 myself for the average) but I'd really like to automate the math parts. I have not found a single way to properly do this - using "=DIVIDE(K2,6)" as a modified version of a suggestion on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637205/dividing-whole-column-in-google-spreadsheet/49637323) (modified to use the column I'm actually putting the numbers in) does literally nothing, and I'd have to manually change and paste it into each row, which is actually harder and more tedious than continuing to do the math myself.

Here's an example image of what my columns look like. All the math is correct so far, I just want to automate it so I can type fewer numbers:

[image: (Apparently I am forced to not actually include the image, but link to it. I have no idea how this helps anyone since this just forces everyone to have more than one tab open, but whatever)]

EDIT: Combined answers from Scott and Player0 is what worked! thanks for being patient with me! I was able to also use that to make the Sum column function automatically as well, so both columns are fully automated now! :D

Comment: Try `=K2/6`. (`/` is commonly used to indicate division.)

Comment: ^ this doesn't work since I would still have to enter the formula manually on every line. This is longer, harder, and more tedious than doing the math myself and entering  the values manually...like I said in my OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to enter the formula manually on every line. 
Enter `=K2/6` in cell `L2`; then select cell `L2`
and drag/fill it down to `L12`. 
(That means click on the dot in the lower right corner of the cell
and drag it down.) 
Or however far your sheet actually goes. 
That will ***automatically*** fill in `L3` with `=K3/6`,
`L4` with `=K4/6`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

use on row 2:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(K2:K/6; 0)
```

also see: [ArrayFormula of Average on Infinite Truly Dynamic Range in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65435313/5632629)

Comment: This did not work. I get "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in [other_cell]"

And that link is honestly not doing much for me since I know that the column count is always going to be the same.

Comment: delete all cells in that column you put this formula in. results will roll out for each row automaticaly